# WordPress 5.9 editor-style.css not working anymore and adds css properties that overrides block styling

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a WP site with the Gutenberg editor styled (the place where you are writing the entry). It worked perfectly until this 5.9 update, where there have been added styles like these ones:

```
html :where(.editor-styles-wrapper) h1,
html :where(.editor-styles-wrapper) h2,
html :where(.editor-styles-wrapper) h3,
html :where(.editor-styles-wrapper) h4,
html :where(.editor-styles-wrapper) h5,
html :where(.editor-styles-wrapper) h6,
html :where(.editor-styles-wrapper) select {
    font-size: revert;
    margin: revert;
    color: revert;
    line-height: revert;
    font-weight: revert
}
```

Is there any way to dequeue those styles? I don't want to dequeue all the editor-styles and calling 1 by 1 each needed style, I need a more scalable solution (because I would have to check if they added new css in every update).

I've noticed that this is not working anymore, maybe it's related:

```
add_theme_support('editor-styles');
add_editor_style( 'editor-style.css' );
```

Answer (score 3):

In WordPress 5.9, [many changes were introduced](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/01/08/updates-for-settings-styles-and-theme-json/) to how styling/theming is done including [theme.json](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/) and [block themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/block-theme-overview/) as part of Full Site Editing. Rather than trying to remove or dequeue the base Editor style defaults, I would try adapting what you have in your themes `editor-style.css` to support blocks and move towards [theme.json](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/) gradually where you can.

For reference, the `where:(.editor-styles-wrapper)` is defined in the Block Library [reset.scss](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/9e4dbfbbddb925e5fca844b8cdb907ba74ae418b/packages/block-library/src/reset.scss#L10) and its stated that those rules are only needed when the block editor is not being loaded in an iframe.

Also, `add_theme_support('editor-styles')` and `add_editor_style('editor-style.css' )` are still supported, its likely that your style being overriden by the Editors CSS reset.